# How to record on CD my Album from Photos App?

Tags: macbook-pro, photos.app, recording

I have an album with some photos (*almost 8 GB, lot of movies*) in my Photos App on Mac. Now I need to save them on DVD. How to do this? Is there a simple way? How to find aprioprate album in Finder?

Answer (score 1):

To move your Photos library to DVD:

1- Make an empty folder in your desktop or any other place in Finder (in a hard drive with at least 8GBs free space).

3- Go to your target album in Photos.app and press Command-A to select all photos in the album.

4- Drag photos from album to the open empty folder.

5- Wait! (It takes a little time. You can see the whole progress in a circular icon at the top of the Photos app, and if you click on it, a normal progress bar will appear, and it tells you the number of exported photos)

6- Burn. Again, press Command-A in the folder, and drag all the media to the empty DVD, and press Burn at the top-right corner of the Finder windows containing DVD.

7- Wait for the burning to DVD process to be completed!

NOTE: There are a lot of apps to help you do this in less time. You can find them with a simple search on Mac App Store.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I haven't found not even one app to do this:-)

Comment: Can you suggest me what app should I install to record album through Photos App's extension?

Comment: I searched in Mac built-in features and found an easier way. The only thing you need is a burn folder, which can be made by File->New Burn Folder in any Finder window. Then all the thing you need to do is dragging pictures into that folder and press burn in that folder. So it is 3 steps (Make Folder, Drag, Click Burn). Don't forget the CD while doing that steps! If you have the old iPhoto, it has a burn feature included, but this is the first version of Photos.app, and this is common in first versions of all softwares and hardwares. I wish this helps you.